# Refactoring Express code and cannot figure out variable scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I hope this is not a silly question.  I have a homepage route that loads up a lot of mongo databases, and I originally had it loop through the mongo databases and add them to an array that was rendered to a webpage.  However, the databases have become more complicated and they need to be populated, so I can no longer use a loop to accomplish this, and needed to refactor to getting the databases individually.  However, I seem to be having problems with the variable's scopes, as they are always returned as empty outside of the .find function.
My original code was this:

```
    const collections = [User, Ticket, Client, Job, Transaction];
    let endCollections = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < collections.length; i++){
        await collections[i].find({}, function(err, foundCollection){ 
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                endCollections[i] = foundCollection;                
            }
        });
    }
    res.render("dashboard", {transactions: endCollections[4], clients: endCollections[2], tickets: endCollections[1], jobs: endCollections[3]});
```

And this worked fine.  But I need to populate the individual databases, so this was no longer useful.  I rewrote it out to populate, but I am having problems changing the global variables inside of the functions.  Here is the new code I am trying:

```
    let transactions = [],
    clients = [],
    jobs = [],
    tickets = [];

    await Transaction.find({}).populate("job").populate("client").populate("deposited_by_user").exec(function(err, foundTransactions){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {                                        
            for (let i = 0; i < foundTransactions.length; i++){
                foundTransactions[i]["transaction_info"]["new_amount"] = numberWithCommas(foundTransactions[i]["transaction_info"]["amount"]);
            }
        }
        transactions = foundTransactions;
    });

    await Client.find({}).populate("transactions").populate("jobs").exec(function(err, foundClients){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        clients = foundClients;
    });

    await Ticket.find({}).populate("created_by").populate("assigned_user").populate("completed_by_user").exec(function(err, foundTickets){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        tickets = foundTickets;
    });

    await Job.find({}).populate("created_by").populate("client").populate("transactions").exec(function(err, foundJobs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        jobs = foundJobs;
    }); 

    res.render("dashboard", {transactions: transactions, clients: clients, tickets: tickets, jobs: jobs});
```

For example, if I console.log "jobs" right after the line jobs = foundJobs;, it will show the jobs array being populated.  However, if I console.log "jobs" right before the res.render, it shows it as empty.  Considering the global variable endCollections in my original code seemed to be changed within the functions before, I am unsure why my new code does not do the same as everything is returned empty.  I know that somehow the scope of the variable is what is wrong here, but I cannot see how.  Is there something obvious I am missing?  Thanks.

Comment: at first glance, this seems to be an asynchronicity problem, not a variable scope problem. To check this, console.log(jobs) twice like u did and add the line number to the log statement. my guess is that the line before res.render() runs first and u will see the log statement with the higher line number first.

Comment: You are right.  On a side note, thank you for suggesting I add the line number to console.log, I never thought of that before and it will make debugging easier.  So, it seems that you are right, and that it seems that res.render is happening before the job portion of it.  I am unsure why this would be; I thought that the "await" part itself was supposed to prevent this?  Thanks.

Comment: Please add a console.log() statement

- a) directly before transactions = foundTransactions;
- b) directly before await Client.find({})
- c) directly before res.render("dashboard",...
and tell me in which order they run

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, according to my console logs, it is going in this order: b) directly before await Client.find({}); c) directly before res.render('dashboard',...; a) directly before transactions = foundTransactions;  From this, it seems that it is jumping down to the res.render first before everything else.  I tried taking the await part out and it seems to still go in this same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here now the answer so it is not buried in the post's comments.

After reading [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), I think you should either use await with an empty exec() or use exec(callback).

What happens when you use both is that exec(callback) sees u passed a callback, it asynchronously executes your query and adds the callback to the promise.then of the query promise to be called once the query promise is settled. Then it immediately returns but it *does not* return the query promise since you passed a callback. The await is simply awaiting the normal (probably void/undefined) return of the function which is why removing it does not change anything.

After awaiting the return of the function, res.render executes and some time after that, the promise that had been created in the exec(callback) call settles and the callback you passed is executed.

So what is the appropriate way of fixing this? I would encourage you to read deeper into async/awai, promises, and the docs I linked above and find it out yourself before you read on, but since the solution is quite simple I'll leave it here.

```js
// your variable declarations
try {
    const foundTransactions = await Transaction.find({}).populate("job").populate("client").populate("deposited_by_user").exec();
    // your for loop
    transactions = foundTransactions;
    // same for the other calls
     tickets: tickets, jobs: jobs});
catch (e) {console.log(e);}
res.render("dashboard", {transactions: transactions, clients: clients,...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  This does exactly what I wanted, which was a clean line of code and not using so many callbacks.  I will admit, I have a tough time understanding the async, await, promise and try functions in Javascript, but I made the mistake of starting to learn with ES5, so I am trying to catch up as I go :) I appreciate you looking through the resources to help!  I will read through it myself, and hopefully I will have a better understanding.